# Is C or C++ better for making portable code?

Tags: c++, c, portability

I am trying to have some fun in summer. Writing a piece of code that enables presenting Arabic language in systems that support Unicode but no support for eastern languages it. I am writing only the logic hopefully with no integration code initially.

Should I use C++ or C?

Which is the easier language to write portable code and easier to integrate with Python possibly?

---

#### Edit:

I am fairly good with C/C++ though I consider myself closer to C++. But It seems it is easier to write C and plug it every where or I am wrong ? I would write some functions to process Arabic Unicode String. presenting Arabic language need some processing because ALMOST ALL characters have different shapes in different contexts.

---

#### Edit:

It seems I will go with C++, just to make it more fun.

Comment: @AraK, this is an extremely broad question.  You may want to try to narrow this a bit.  As it stands it's practically impossible to give you a good answer.

Comment: Why does it need to be C/C++ ? .NET and Java have better Unicode support...

Comment: I think you're right. It's hard to get more portable than C with a compiled language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use C++, mostly because it provides a lot more "stuff" to use and as far as my experience goes is as portable as C. However, I have not used straight C/C compiler for 10 years or more.

---

#### EDIT

A commenter questioned my experience with portability. Mine is limited to Linux and Win32 primarily. I assumed this would be sufficient OSes for this exercise.

Comment: I'm curious, how many different operating systems did your software support regarding C++ begin more portable than C?

Comment: I like C++ and C more basically. I believe it is harder to integrate with other languages ? Window and Linux.

Comment: @Todd - Your point is well-taken - I am currently only talking about linux, unix and Win32/win64.  I have no experience with others, so my reading of portable and cross platform is effectively for those.  I have found no problem with c++ portability on those platforms.   I am sure there are lots of examples of other platforms, but given the context of MOST problems those are the platforms of interest.  (aside from mac as well)

Comment: From what I've seen on the iPhone, it's a bit saner to use C libraries from Objective-C than it is to use C++ libraries with objective-C. The support _is_ there for C++, but C libraries seem the norm, and iPhone programmers are used to C libraries. I'll stick with C as being more portable.

Comment: I didn't really comment on apple products.  They are in their own special world...

Comment: If you write a C library, just about everyone is in the same world.

Comment: How are apple products in their own special world? OS X and iPhone OS both run on BSD...

Answer (score 5):

I strongly disagree with the assertion that C and C++ are comparable when portability is a concern. True, if you limit yourself to recent Visual Studio and g++, C++ is "portable". But things like boost are a maintenance nightmare if you care about more platforms than that (older gcc/visual studio, many other old compilers on proprietary unices). In this context, C is much more portable than C++ in my experience. If you look at most open source projects which use C++ (mozilla, some google code) , they limit themselves to a very restricted subset of C++.

Now, for strings handling, I would say that both C and C++ are quite bad languages :) I would certainly look at something much higher level, with good support for unicode string handling.

Answer (score 3):

If it's for fun, go for the language you want to learn better.

I'd bet that there are more recent libraries to support various language packs in C++, but maybe that's part of the fun, is to write your own version in C.

Answer (score 3):

I would write it in C++ and provide a C interface to get the widest possible integration footprint.  Also, you can use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to generate wrappers to many common languages.

Answer (score 2):

Try to see next sites:

["boost.org/"](http://boost.org/) (see the integration with python)

or

["pocoproject.org/"](http://pocoproject.org/)

Both sites seems to have the sympathy of Stroustrup, the creator of C++

Comment: Anybody have experience with the pocoproject.org library?  It looks very interesting.  I want to get into iPhone development (seems a lot of people do), but I don't want to go back to the "C" part of Objective-C.  I have been leaning towards Objective-C++, but not sure what c++ library to use.

Answer (score 2):

You need robust **library** support. For that, C++ has more rich options. If you use a framework like [QT](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products) it will be almost trivial. It's also very portable over all systems. Integrating with Python is also straightforward (though for that I like [boost::python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/python/doc/index.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Either one of C or C++ should enable you to write portable code if you're careful.  For Unicode handling, you will likely also want a Unicode-aware string facility; for C, Glib can be quite useful.

Of course, you could just write it in Python from the beginning.  That is reasonably portable, and probably easiest.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to write in C.Because C will provide you more ways of producing optimized and portable code than C++.If you do it in C then it will be easier to integrate with python.

Comment: I never tried to write something to integrate with python. Is it easier to write C library for python or use Boost::python ? I never tried to do either!

Comment: boost::python has two big issues: it is very slow to compile, and boost is not portable. If you only care about recent platforms (win32 + VS 2005 and above, linux and gcc 4.x), then it is less a problem. But if you need to support tens of platforms, boost is a no-no IMHO.

Comment: To wrap a C API, my recommended tool is cython. It is not as automatic as boost, but I found it easier to use. If you have a big API to wrap, then you may want to look into something else.